# LINQ with multiple columns and operations

Tags: c#, .net, linq, t-sql, entities

i'm trying to do this on LINQ:

```
select p.ProductID, p.ArticleCode, SUM((case h.OperationType when 0 then 1 else -1 end) * h.[Count])
from Products p
inner join StockItems s on p.ArticleCode = s.ArticleCode
inner join StockHistorical h on s.ArticleID = h.ArticleID
where h.[Date] < '23/08/2013 11:30:00'
group by p.ProductID, p.ArticleCode
```

I have this:

```
        var products = (from p in e.Products
                        join s in e.StockItems on p.ArticleCode equals s.ArticleCode
                        join h in e.StockHistoricals on s.ArticleID equals h.ArticleID
                        where h.Date < DateTime.Parse("23/08/2013 11:30:00")
                        group p by p.ProductID into StockResult
                        select new {  });
```

Anyone know how can i do the

`SUM((case h.OperationType when 0 then 1 else -1 end) * h.[Count])`

with LINQ?

Thanks!

I forgot to say that the problem is the "group by", because i can't access the OperationType property in the StockResult group.

**Solved! The key is the:**

```
let combined = new 
{
    Product = p,
    HistoryCount = (h.OperationType == 0 ? 1 : -1) * h.Count
}
```

Comment: You can take the result and then can apply all changes in the same, like withing foreach for result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
...
let combined = new 
{
    Product = p,
    HistoryCount = (h.OperationType == 0 ? 1 : -1) * h.Count
}
group combined by combined.Product.ProductID into StockResult
select new
{
    ProductID = StockResult.Key,
    Total = StockResult.Sum(x => x.HistoryCount)
}
```

Comment: don't need `return` since it's still a single-statement expression.  `return` is implied.

Comment: yes, but the group by doesn't let me use the "h.", and in the StockResult i can't use the OperationType property :s. the problem is that i need to multiply the h.Count by (1 or -1) depending if the operation is an input (0) or output (1).

Comment: @tincho87 do you need the sum of `h` within the context of the grouping or per product?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a direct translation, but I'd go with:

```
(h.Count(his => his.OperationType != 0) 
    - h.Count(his => his.OperationType == 0))
    * h.Count()
```

It should be functionally equivalent, and seems to better represent what you're trying to do.

Comment: Three `Count` calls? Is there not a better way?

Comment: @mattytommo It's all done on the database, which should be able to optimize it down quite well.  Were it Linq to objects I'd actually search for something more optimal over something stating the underlying algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do something like this?
I am not sure this is going to work.

```
select new
{
S=Sum(((h.OperationType)!=0?-1:1)*h.Count)
}
```

Comment: You're missing the start of the lambda in your `Sum` call.